# How to run Streets of Rage 5 remake on Ubuntu (Natively)?

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, games, ubuntu-gnome

I downloaded Streets of Rage 5 *from bomber games* on my computer running Ubuntu but I am unable to make it work!
I edited the file sorr to include my directories which made the application launch and even load the game manual, but won't start the game! Am I missing something here?

- The only window I got

[image: The only window I got]

I edited it so it includes the deb file that @luchonacho uploaded for me!

Comment: The page you provided through a link is reported as a `Deceptive Site` by Firefox

Comment: It's just a download link for a gz archive!

Comment: I am unable to find a working download link for this game, the one you edited out also does not work. Can you give a live link? Suggestions I have seen for successfully running the game on 64bit: `sudo apt-get install libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386` and for 32bit: `sudo apt-get install libasound2 libasound2-plugins`. More than happy to test this out if I can find a live download link.....

Comment: @luchonacho Looks like Sega muscled out this version a while back....

Comment: @MuaadElSharif Added the linux version to the answer. Maybe the file was problematic. **It works perfectly for me**.

Comment: @andrew.46 I found the file. Check my answer. Hopefully it will work for you too.

Comment: The downloaded file worked for you without any steps?

Comment: @MuaadElSharif No extra steps. Just what I added in the answer. Did it work for you? Actually, which Ubuntu do you have? It would be useful to know.

Comment: You just made my day @luchonacho

Comment: @MuaadElSharif, so, the problem was that the file you had was corrupted, or something like that? (don't forget to mark the answer as solved :) )

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with the tar.gz file, but the .deb you uploaded worked like a charm, thank you @luchonacho

Comment: @luchonacho Please keep the google drive file and don't delete it!

Comment: @MuaadElSharif It's not mine (it's from [this guy](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/STDexperience/discussions/6/348293292501024528/)). I suggest you save it, and maybe upload it somewhere else (personal web, etc).

Comment: OK cool @luchonacho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Native (linux) instructions for Ubuntu 16.04**

Download the .deb file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0xypeLm7EKgNFpLMzRaZnlTMDQ/view). Then, open a terminal, `cd` into the file, and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i sorr_5.1-1ug_amd64.deb
```

This installs the game on the computer. It automatically installs a launcher. Thus, you can open it from the Menu.

*File source:* [*here*](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/STDexperience/discussions/6/348293292501024528/).

---

**Wine instructions for Ubuntu 16.04**

The following instructions allow you to play *Streets of Rage Remake v5.1* using Wine (I have version 1.9.24, but it might work in others too).

- In case you do not have it already, install `wine`. You can get the [current version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/wine) (1.6) by running `sudo apt-get install wine`. For the latest build, follow [these instructions](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

  ```
  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
  ```
- Download the Windows version of the game from [here](http://www.sorrcommunity.com/t27-downloads-streets-of-rage-remake-v5-1-ports-and-soundtrack). (there are some extra soundtracks in the last post)
- Extract the `.rar` file in your local folder, wherever you want. This will create a `SORRv5.1` folder.
- Run the `SorR.exe` file with wine. Double-clicking it might be enough. If not, right-click on the file, and select "Open with Wine Windows Program Loader".

---

**Meny entry**: additionally to the above, you can create a Menu entry for the game, so that you can run easily from the Menu. To do so, open a terminal and run the following:

```
    cd ~/.local/share/applications/
    sudo nano SorR.desktop
```

The first command take you to the folder where `.desktop` files (and menu entries) are stored. The second creates a file. Then, copy the text below into that file (with right-click or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>):

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Name=Streets of Rage Remake
    Exec= wine /path/to/SORRv5.1/SorR.exe
    Icon=/path/to/SORRv5.1/manual/img/sorr.png
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application
    Categories=Games;
```

Replace `/path/to/` with the corresponding path, and select the image you would like as icon, in case the one I chose is not of your like. once you have copied that, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save. To exit, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Now, your menu entry is in the Games folder.

---

**In-game instructions**. The games comes configured for joystick. If you do not have one, then change the Controls commands, where you can select keyboard instead of joystick.

That's it. Sound works fine. Enjoy!

[image]